# Performance of SciChart WPF on Remote Desktop / Citrix server

Tags: c#, wpf, rdp, citrix, scichart

We are considering using SciChart (WPF), but only if its performance is ‘reasonable’ across Remote Desktop / or via Citrix Server. Has SciChart addressed the known problems of using WPF applications across RDP / Citrix? If so, could you provide some stats as to the performance across RDP?

The reason we are asking is that our current software in which we are using our own high speed rendering is doing fine with a lot of data on the local machine, but is not doing so well across RDP. This is not a huge surprise given the known issues of WPF and RDP (for example see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1005739/246758). We may need to deal with this slowness as more of our customers are using Citrix-servers to run our software.

Any feedback on performance of SciChart across RDP / or using Citrix would be much appreciated!

Comment: This question was asked on the SciChart WPF Chart Forums and has been answered there - hope this helps! https://www.scichart.com/questions/question/performance-of-scichart-wpf-on-remote-desktop-citrix-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [SciChart Forums](https://www.scichart.com/questions/wpf/performance-of-scichart-wpf-on-remote-desktop-citrix-server):

> SciChart performance will be entirely unaffected by RDP entirely so long as the remote machine has adequate hardware to run SciChart. For example, running the application without dropping down to software rendering. The bottleneck then becomes streaming the image of the updating chart over the internet.
>
> In order to reduce the load that SciChart places on RDP bandwidth, you can limit the frame rate using the SciChartSurface.MaxFrameRate property when in RDP mode
>   Disable animations on zoom by setting properties such as RubberBandXyZoomModifier.IsAnimated = false, and ZoomExtentsModifier.IsAnimated = false.
>
> By disabling animations and reducing frame rate, the number of redraws/second will be reduced and this will reduce the load on your internet bandwidth when viewing an application with SciChart over RDP.