# WPF application render issue

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, render

I have a WPF application which somethimes behaves strange on different machines. 
This is the main screen of the application:

[image]

On some machines it looks like this on startup and you have to find the minimize and restore it to get fully rendered which is really annoying.

[image]

Any suggestions how to troubleshoot this problem or a possible fix?

Comment: Do you have the same directx version on both computer?
Does the first screen comes from TeamViewer too?

Comment: Did you check that the graphic driver is up-to-date ?

Comment: Forget about my first comment on Directx.
I think our probleme should be close to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244010/wpf-not-rendering-on-remote-desktop

Answer (score -1):

Disabling hardware accelleration by creating a DWORD registry value at

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics\DisableHWAcceleration

and then setting it to 1.

There seems to be confusion between graphics card drivers and OS updates.